# Screen saver on different monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screensaver

Can I have different screen savers on different monitors?

I have three monitors configured as:

```
[Desktop]---Main Board ---- Monitor 1
   |
   |- VGA Card - Monitor 2
   |
   `- VGA Card - Monitor 3
```

Mainly I'm working with Monitor 2, and I want the screen saver turn off Monitor 1, 3 for 30 minutes timeout. And turn on each monitor when mouse in.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it's complicated and you lose drag and drop between monitors.

The setup would be something like setting up 3 different X sessions, one on each monitor.

Turning off your system setting based screensaver.

Adding a screensaver daemon for each x session with the settings file you want in the tweaked xinitrc for each xsession.  Here's some info on [custom xinitrc](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession).